# Segmentation Fault error when closing files

Tags: c, file, pointers, fault

All,

I'm having a terrible time attempting to figure out why I keep getting these segmentation faults. I am trying to open a file on a server, read from it, close it. Everything seems to be going well until I attempt to close the file. These subroutines are called one at a time from the same program. When monthly rain is called, it prints out a value of 22 for the pointer using the code below. When daily rain runs, the pointer value prints out as (null). If either fclose is uncommented, the program stops working and displays segmentation fault when the fclose line is reached. I am opening the same file in both routines. In main, monthly rain is called before daily rain. Please ask if you need any more information, any help is greatly appreciated!!

The routines are as follows:

```
float monthly_rain(int year, int month)
{   
    float mon_rain=0, mrain, rain1, rain2, d, cur_hour=0, day;
    char filename[size];
    FILE *afile;

    //calculates monthly rainfail
    for(d=1;d<day;d++)
    {
        sprintf(filename, "%s%4d%02d%02d.dat",ARCHIVEDIR,year,month);   //step through the days of the month(d not mday)
        printf("\nFilename is = %s\n", filename);
        if((afile=fopen(filename, "r"))!= NULL)
        {
            if(d==1)    //Get first reading of the month - total rain is 9th column 
                mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d", &rain1); 
            else    //scan till you reach the last day of the month
            {   //Step through the columns, exit when last day reached
                cur_hour=0;     //resets current hour counter for each new day
                while ((mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*c", &rain2))!= -1)   
                    cur_hour++;     //probable wont need this till daily calculation, unless we really want it in monthly too.
            }
        }
    }
    mon_rain=(rain2*.01)-(rain1*.01);   //Save the monthly reading
    printf("\nMon rain as in func. %.2f\n", mon_rain);
    printf("\npointer = %d\n", afile);  
    //fclose(afile);
    printf("\n\nflag 1\n\n");
    return mon_rain;
}//end monthly rainfall calc.
```

and

```
float daily_rain(int year, int month, int day)
{
    float daily_rain=0, mrain, rain1, rain2, cur_hour=0;
    char filename[size];
    FILE *afile;

    //daily rainfall calc.
    sprintf(filename, "%s%4d%02d%02d.dat",ARCHIVEDIR, year, month, day);    //get the current days archive file
    printf("\nFilename is = %s\n", filename);
    if((afile=fopen(filename, "r"))!= NULL)     //open the file
    {
        //Step through the columns, exit when last day reached
        while ((mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*c", &rain2))!= -1)
        {
            if(cur_hour==0)
                rain1=rain2;                //save the first reading of the day
            cur_hour++;
        }
    }
    daily_rain=(rain2*.01)-(rain1*.01);     //the daily rainfall saved here
    printf("\nDaily rain as in func. %.2f\n", daily_rain);
    printf("\npointer = %s\n", afile);
    //fclose(afile);
    return daily_rain;
}//end daily rainfall calc.
```

Some additions to help clarify some questions...

The %*d place holder is used to ignore the next integer. I am reading the 9th column in a 15 column data file. I'm not running into any problems getting the data so far. Size is also defined as 100.

Thanks again.

Comment: `"%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*c"` what are you doing there?

Comment: @MikeDinescu: I wondered the same, but there actually is one solitary `%d` in there.

Comment: what is `size` ? If it is negative or zero, this is bad, and if it's too big it may cause a stack overflow.

Comment: change `sprintf(filename` to `snprintf(filename, sizeof filename`

Comment: in this code block, begining with: if((afile=fopen(filename, "r"))!= NULL) the code fails to handle the case of 'afile' being NULL, rather it just jumps to the next line after the code block and keeps on running.

Comment: this line: mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d", &rain1); should raise an error due to the number of receiving variables (1) does not match the number of format items (15).  Also the code is missing the check to assure that all the parameters have been read.

Comment: this line:  if((afile=fopen(filename, "r"))!= NULL) is inside the body of a 'for' loop, so gets executed many times.  That is an error, it should be outside the 'for' loop.  This is why the 'close' fails.

Answer (score 2):

Numerous problems, here.

You should only attempt to `fclose()` a file if you successfully `fopen()`ed it. Change to:

```
    if((afile=fopen(filename, "r"))!= NULL)
    {
        if(d==1)
            mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d", &rain1); 
        else 
        { 
            cur_hour=0; 
            while ((mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*c", &rain2))!= -1)   
                cur_hour++;
        }

        fclose(afile);  /*  <---- close it here, not at the end  */
    }
```

Currently, in all cases the best your code can hope to do is close the last file you opened. If the last thing you set `afile` to was `NULL`, you'll crash.

Further, if your `fopen()` call fails, then don't continue with the rest of your logic.

For instance, `daily_rain=(rain2*.01)-(rain1*.01);` and friends in your `daily_rain()` will run even if your file did not open and `rain1` and `rain2` are uninitialized, which is bad. Move that stuff inside your `if` block, too, so it only runs with a successful file open.

Your loops also fail to account for the fact that `fscanf()` can return `EOF`. Right now you seem to want to terminate when `fscanf()` returns `0`, but if it returns `EOF` you'll just keep right on going.

Also, also, when you call this:

```
for(d=1;d<day;d++)
```

`day` is uninitialized, so this loop is likely to run for a long, long time.

Comment: `while ((mrain = fscanf( afile, "%*d:%*d...%*d%*c", &rain2))!= -1)` does not insure `rain2` is ever assigned a value.  And `rain2` is a `float`.  Agree: Numerous problems in OP post".

Comment: Paul, Thanks for your assistance. I made the changes you suggested and it worked well! I should have seen these errors, but I'm glad you were able to help. Day is passed into the function from main and is the actual day of the month.

Comment: @Rdemps: Not in `monthly_rain()`, it's not, you define `day` in the first line, but never initialize it.

Comment: You're definitely correct here Paul. I did make the change though before coming back here. Must have been right after I posted this. I guess I caught that mistake, which is good.